# Knitr and rmarkdown will not add figure captions to the output

Tags: captions, r, knitr, markdown, rstudio

I am writing a report on Rmarkdown and knitr using RStudio, and cannot find a way to get figure captions on my document. My code for the chunk where I try to plot is like:

````
```{r fig1,fig.width=4,fig.height=4,echo=FALSE,message=FALSE,include=TRUE,fig.cap="Caption"}

plot(rnorm(100,2),rnorm(100,8))
```
````

No caption is added to the pdf output, and a look at the intermediary latex file reveals that the figure environment is not created:

```
\includegraphics{./Untitled_files/figure-latex/fig.pdf}
```

Otherwise, the pdf document is created without any problems, it just misses the captions.
I have read in the knitr manual and in many other questions about the topic that the chunk option fig.cap will add the figure environment. I tried to add the fig.env=TRUE option, as well, but the results are the same. Is this an issue with rmarkdown in rstudio only or is it that in general it will not work?

Comment: How are you converting from `.Rmd` to `.pdf`?

Comment: Using knitr and pdfLaTex. Knitr produces a .tex file and pdfLaTex takes over from there, I suppose.

Comment: Calling `knit()` on an `.Rmd` file will produce `.md` output, though. How exactly are you going from `.Rmd` to a `.tex` file?

Comment: And `knit2pdf()` only works on `.Rnw` files and `.Rrst` files.

Comment: I use the built in functionality in RStudio. It works alright and outputs the PDF, it just fails to add a caption.

Comment: Ah, okay. Makes sense. I hadn't updated RStudio in a while, so I didn't know that that was possible. Looks like you got an answer that works. Glad the problem was solved! `:)`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try adding `fig_caption: yes` to the YAML header of your .Rmd file. It will look something like this:

```
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Nicholas"
date: "20/09/2014"
output:
  pdf_document:
    fig_caption: yes
---
```

There's more information here: http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/pdf_document_format.html